# how to hide show different components in one component ionic 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

I have a component called **HomeComponent** . In that I need to show multiple component based on condition .

[image]

I have my functionalities in one page calling different pages , into Home component . I am using a *ngIf to show hide the div's (is my current logic running in my brain :-( ). In this way I am stuck at a problem . When I click on **component mars**, I have to show **component pluto** , so one .

home.component.html

```
    <ion-home>
         <ion-content *ngIf="mars==true">
            <component-mars>
               //consider this as the code inside the component plz
                 <button (click)="gotoPluto()">component mars</button>
            </component-mars>
         </ion-content>

         <ion-content *ngIf="pluto==false">
           <component-pluto>
                 //consider this as the code inside the component plz
                 <button (click)="gotoEarth()">component mars</button>
           </component-pluto>
         </ion-content>
      </ion-home>
```

mars.component.ts

```
     gotoPluto(){

        mars= false; // so the mars should hide
        pluto=false; //so the pluto will hide and show earth
       }
```

how can my home component detect this . I tried to use ion-tabs navController but it has tab-bar . I already hav my buttons in specified components.

Comment: what about using ngSwitch?

Comment: Hi I found and answer which is working fine . that is using Events . I able to view different views . I am using the same *ngIf conditions . I am able to change the conditions using the event emmit reference [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) . But problem is i have to pass the data also as i was doing before using the navCtrl.push . Currently for my solution i am using the localstorage

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Ionic framework so this may need tweaking (not tested) but might give you an idea of how to approach this using `ngSwitch`.

#### Home Component Template

1. You can adjust your template to add `ngSwitch` on the `<ion-home>` tag passing in the variable to switch on.  In this case we're switching on `currentPlanet`.
2. Then you'll add `ngSwitchWhen` on the `<ion-content>` tag passing in a string value.  The string value should be the value you want current planet to be in order to have that content shown.  So when `currentPlanet = 'mars'` the element `<ion-content *ngSwitchWhen="'mars'">` will be shown.
3. Add a click event on the planet component tag calling the `nextPlanet(string)` function in `home.component.ts` passing in a string value of the next planet to go to.

---

```
<ion-home [ngSwitch]="currentPlanet">
  <ion-content *ngSwitchWhen="'mars'">
    <component-mars 
        (click)="nextPlanet('pluto')">
    </component-mars>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-content *ngSwitchWhen="'pluto'>
    <component-pluto 
        (click)="nextPlanet('earth')">
    </component-pluto>
  </ion-content>
</ion-home>
```

#### Home Component Typescript File

You will then have your `nextPlanet()` function in your `home.component.ts` component.  The home component will dictate which planet component to show based on a single variable `currentPlanet`.

```
currentPlanet: string = 'mars';

nextPlanet(planet: string){
  this.currentPlanet = planet;
}
```

Now when the component is clicked on it will call the `nextPlanet()` function in the home controller passing in the string value of the next planet.

Comment: Hi , I am having a issue , I have used the *ngIf to hide show the components . The problem I am facing is view is , second time the view is not updating